# Degree sequences of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

The question is, for which values of $n$ is $0, 1, \cdots , n - 1$ a degree sequence of some graph.

I know that for $n > 1$, this is not possible for simple graphs, however, I'm not sure of the answer in the case of arbitrary graphs.

I've noticed that $\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} k = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}$ which can possibly be an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following proposition: The nonnegative integers $d_1,...,d_n$ are the vertex degrees of some graph if and only if $\sum d_i$ is even. A proof for this statement may be found, for example, in Douglas West's *Introduction to Graph Theory* (on the page 44 in the second edition). Then, in your question, inspect the parity of $$\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$ according to the possibilities of $n$ mod $4$. You will get $n\equiv0 \ \mbox{mod} \ 4$ or $n\equiv1 \ \mbox{mod} \ 4$.